# Problem when I create relationship on one table and get two columns from that table

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am new to flask and web development. I am creating some tables for practice and this is the problem:

- I created two tables `student` and `subject`
- Now when I add a relationship between them and access `student.id` via foreign key its fine but when I try to access the student.result which is integer it gives me an error below is my DB model code.

```py
class Students(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'students'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80))
    result = db.Column(db.Integer)
    admins = db.relationship("Subjects", lazy="dynamic")


class Subjects(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'subjects'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80))
    student = db.relationship("Student", lazy="dynamic")
    student_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("students.id"))
    student_result = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("students.result"))
```

Error adding record:

```
foreign key mismatch - "subjects" referencing "students" (INSERT INTO `subjects`(`id`,`name`,`student_id`,`student_result`) VALUES (1,NULL,NULL,NULL);)
```

Comment: I don't know what the whole problem is, but your "student" relationship is referencing the non-existent "Student" class.

Comment: I want to know that foreign key can only access the primary keys of any column? not any other column? please clear my confusion

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for asking about that other detail. I think the problem here is that your `student_result` relationship isn't actually a foreign key.

While your foreign key does not necessarily need to reference a primary key, it *does* have to reference a [unique column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106642/sqlalchemy-foreign-keys-works-only-with-primary-key). Primary keys are guaranteed to be unique. In your class structure, you should get a `student`'s `result` by joining the tables on the `student_id` foreign key. You shouldn't have a `student_result` relationship at all.

```
    results = db.session.query(Students, Subjects) \
               .join(Students, Students.id == Subjects.student_id) \
               .all()
```

As an aside, it's really confusing to give your class names a plural. I'd recommend singularizing on Student and Subject. (It DOES make sense for the tablename to be pluralized, though.)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! If this answer resolved the issue, I'd appreciate it if you could accept it.